# Problemswith DropDownList in customized ASP.NET CreateUserWizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, drop-down-menu, createuserwizard

I am using a customized `ASP.NET CreateUserWizard` in my web application.

Here I used a `dropdownlist` to populate the countries when user registering. In the `page load` its populate the countries as expected.

```
var query = GetNationality();
var national = (DropDownList)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Nationality");
national.DataSource = query;
national.DataTextField = "CountryName";
national.DataValueField = "Id";
national.DataBind();

var item = new ListItem("Select Country", "");
national.Items.Insert(0, item);
```

But when I trying to obtain the values from `dropdownlist` in the `OnCreatedUser` event it generating me an error saying

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

What I am doing in the is `OnCreatedUser` is

```
var national = (DropDownList)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Nationality");

var nationality = Convert.ToInt32(national.SelectedValue); <<-(where the error is)
```

The complete code of the page is below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FillDropdown();
        }

    }
    protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newUser = Membership.GetUser(RegisterUser.UserName);
        var newUserId = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey;

        var name1 = (TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("fname");
        var name2 = (TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("lname");
        var comp = (TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Company");
        var post = (TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Position");
        var birth = (TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Bday");
        var mob = (TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Mobile");
        var aphone = (TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("altPhone");
        var aemail = (TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("altEmail");
        var national = (DropDownList)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Nationality");      
        var news = (CheckBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Newsletter");

        var title = tit.Text.Trim();        
        var nationality = national.Text;
        var preferred = method.Text.Trim();
        var newsleter = news.Checked;


        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

        var continueUrl = RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(continueUrl))
        {
            continueUrl = "~/";
        }
        Response.Redirect(continueUrl);
    }

    public void FillDropdown()
    {
        var query = GetNationality();
        var national = (DropDownList)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Nationality");
        national.DataSource = query;
        national.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        national.DataValueField = "Id";
        national.DataBind();
        var item = new ListItem("Select Country", "");
        national.Items.Insert(0, item);
    }
```

}

Any ideas will be appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the var nationality line.  what value do you have for national?  what value is national.SelectedValue ?

Comment: yes I already did that but it didn't picking up the value

Comment: Check if you have viewstate enabled for the dropdown or the createuserwizard.

Comment: viewstate is not enabled in the dropdown, do i need to enable that?

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the code that populates `DropDownList` in `Page_Load` method under `!IsPostBack`?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        var query = GetNationality();
        var national = (DropDownList)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Nationality");
        national.DataSource = query;
        national.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        national.DataValueField = "Id";
        national.DataBind();

        var item = new ListItem("Select Country", "");
        national.Items.Insert(0, item);
    }
}
```

It could be that when you postback, your DropDownList gets re-bound, so you always get the first item and you tried to convert empty string to an int which gives you the error message.

Comment: Debug your application and see what is converted into int, which DropDownList item it is.

Comment: for the SelectedIndex it picking up -1. I try using var nationality = national.Text and it picking "" as the value

Comment: Can you post more code (complete one)? Then we can help pin point where the problem is. thanks

Comment: I have edited the question. you can find the full code there. thanks